# Advantages of using Hibernate over Open JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to use Hibernate in my application(In combination with Spring).
so I would like to know what are the general advantages of using Spring Hibernate over Spring Open JPA?
I have seen many links but did not get the clear idea.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

- Here is a performance comparison statistics for a test and the results of the tests per JPA implementation library.

  For this test the time was fixed to 30 minutes of running.

[image]

- The following chart presents results of a specific test(persisting simple entity objects in batches of 5000 per transactions)

[image]

**Information sources** : [Soruce 1](http://terrazadearavaca.blogspot.com/2008/12/jpa-implementations-comparison.html) , [Source 2](https://dzone.com/articles/new-jpa-performance-benchmark)

Hope this helps.